# ffmpeg creating mpeg-dash chunk files too slowly resulting in 404 errors

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

I have a hardware encoder feeding FFmpeg to create a MPEG-DASH Low Latency stream. It works well for a while, but after letting FFmpeg run for a while and reloading the page there are many 404 errors.

When that happens, the `dash.js` player tries to fetch the segment file on the "live edge" but the file has not been created yet by FFmpeg. For example, after running for 20-30 minutes and loading the web page player, debug code in the web server shows:

```
2021-07-16 16:46:30.64 : GET REQUEST : /data/ott/chunk-stream0-00702.m4s
2021-07-16 16:46:30.67 : NOT FOUND. Latest files on filesystem:
    chunk-stream0-00699.m4s.tmp
    chunk-stream0-00698.m4s
    chunk-stream0-00697.m4s
    chunk-stream0-00696.m4s
    ...
```

So you can see the browser requested chunk 702 but the latest on the server is (part of) 699.  With 2 second chunks, that is 3-5 seconds of content not yet available.

To analyze, I modified FFmpeg's `dashenc.c` to add a timestamp every time a file is opened which displays like:

```
[dash @ 0x9b17c0] 21:48:52.935 1626443332.935  : dashenc_io_open() - opened /data/ott/chunk-stream0-00060.m4s.tmp
```

And loaded the timestamps into Excel.

Despite a segment duration of 2.000 seconds, the average time between file opens is 2.011 seconds.  Over two hours this accumulated to a **45 second** difference between the calculated live edge and the latest file on the server.

The HW encoder is set to 25 fps and a GOP size of 5.  I've confirmed both by analyzing the H.264 NALUs output by the HW encoder.

**My Question:** Is this a bug in FFmpeg or can I avoid this problem by adjusting the settings of either the HW encoder and/or FFmpeg options?

**REFERENCE**

```
FFmpeg: Version 4.4 
Centos 8 
Apache 2.4.37
```

*FFmpeg command line (pipe is fed by process reading HW encoder)*

```
ffmpeg -re -loglevel verbose -an -f h264 -i pipe:17 -c:v copy \
-f dash -dash_segment_type mp4 -b:v 1000000 -seg_duration 2.000000 \
-frag_type duration -frag_duration 0.200000 -target_latency 1 \
-window_size 10 -extra_window_size 5 -remove_at_exit 1 -streaming 1 \
-ldash 1 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 0 -write_prft 1 -avioflags direct \
-fflags +nobuffer+flush_packets -format_options movflags=+cmaf \
-utc_timing_url /web/be/time.php /data/ott/master.mpd
```

*Modified `dash_io_open()` from dashenc.c*

```
static int 
dashenc_io_open(AVFormatContext *s, AVIOContext **pb, char *filename, AVDictionary **options)
{
    DASHContext *c = s->priv_data;
    int http_base_proto = filename ? ff_is_http_proto(filename) : 0;
    int err = AVERROR_MUXER_NOT_FOUND;
    if (!*pb || !http_base_proto || !c->http_persistent)
    {
        err = s->io_open(s, pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, options);

        // My Debug
        {
            char buf[20], milli[60];
            struct timeb tp;

            ftime(&tp); // sec + ms
            struct tm *tmInfo = localtime(&tp.time);

            // 2020-05-15 21:15:12.123
            strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%H:%M:%S", tmInfo);
            snprintf(milli, 59, "%s.%03d %d.%03d ", buf, tp.millitm, tp.time, tp.millitm);

            av_log(s, AV_LOG_INFO, "%s : dashenc_io_open() - opened %s\n", milli, filename);
        }
    }
    return err;
}
```